# Chrome not loading website when Google Fonts are installed/running

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-font-api

I have a website that's using the Open Sans typeface from Google Fonts. Now for some reason, when I have Open Sans running (either by using the embed codes provided on the Google Fonts website or by using @type-face to store the fonts locally) the site will sporadically fail to load at all. It may load the first time you get to the site but if you try to refresh the page it stalls and you have to close the tab to proceed.

This ONLY ever happens in Chrome.

I've been working on this issue for a whole day now and I've come to my wit's end.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated. Let me know if further info is needed.

I'm using OSX version 10.9.2 and Chrome version 35.0.1916.153

Cheers.

Comment: 1) Any errors in the console? 2) What code are you using to include the font(s)? 3) Can you elaborate on "fail to load at all?"

Comment: @Mooseman 1) No errors in the console but if I look at the network tab while the site loads I can see that it begins to load resources until it gets to something called "google themes" and then all else returns as "pending". 2) I am using the code Google provides on their fonts site: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>. 3) By "fails to load at all" I mean the page spins for about 1 - 5 minutes and then give me an error message with a choice to either "kill the page" or "wait"

Comment: `http://themes.googleusercontent.com/`... is where the `.woff` font files are loaded from. It's working for me, so I can't help you from what you've posted.